# redis use range of numbers with KEYS

Tags: redis

I have some keys called `Events:21039-lat:101.2321-long:24.3143`.  Now, I'd like to search for all keys where it goes something like this: `Events:*-lat:[any number between 99.2321 and 103.2321]-long:[any number between 23.3143 and 25.3143]`.

The reason why I'm deciding to use keys is because there are not many events written to, therefore I can have many many read slaves, and otherwise I'd have to do this calculation in a highly non-scaleable way w. mysql.  Is there a better way with/without redis though?

Comment: Accept the below answer if it worked foryou

Answer (score 3):

Usage of keys in a production environment is not recommended. It's time complexity is `O(N)` with N being the number of keys in the database. (source: http://redis.io/commands/keys)

You can maintain a bunch of `Events:*` keys in a [set](http://redis.io/commands#set). Read the `set` using `sMembers()` and fetch those keys.

In case you're worried about an additional network call, use a pipeline.